# Linking multiple Models to an Image model through a Gallery model

Tags: django

I am trying to link multiple models (CoolModel and OtherModel in this example) to a Gallery Model...which in turn will have multiple Images. So a CoolModel can have multiple pics and an OtherModel can have multiple pics...all stored in the same (Image) table.

I THINK this is how it is supposed to be laid out, but I am unclear on how I would manipulate (create/delete) instances of CoolModel and OtherModel. Can someone please provide sample code to create a CoolModel and assign a couple of pics to it?

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
# not sure how to link this to Image...or if it even has to be?

class Image(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')

class CoolModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    images = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    images = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you need to look at a ManyToMany relationship. some of your images my end up in duplicate galleries.  At this point if you have a foreignkey relationship the image will only be able to belong to one particular Gallery.  This may be what you want but images can sometimes fall into several categories.   I would think you would want a manytomany to your gallery so you can have gallery entry "sports, stars" could all apply to Lebron James cool image etc...

Comment: Images will only belong to a single gallery, and a gallery will only belong to s single instance of a model (CoolModel, OtherModel, etc etc). I simply need the Gallery model to act as a "middle man" between various models (again, OtherModel, CoolModel, and more) and ultimately pointing to a set of records in the Image model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't totally understand what you are looking to achieve, but it sounds similar to a playlist or, as in [this example from the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), a ManyToMany relationship through an intermediary. Here is an example based on a total shot-in-the-dark guess as to what kind of relationship you are looking for (because I don't really know what 'CoolModel' is supposed to do or be for):

```
class CoolModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    other attributes

class Gallery(models.Model):
    coolmodel = models.ManyToMany(CoolModel, through='Image')

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
    coolmodel = models.ForeignKey(CoolModel)
```

The key to the intermediary is exploiting the `through` parameter, and the docs have some good examples about how to insert objects using these relationships (copied from the documentation):

```
>>> ringo = Person.objects.create(name="Ringo Starr")
>>> paul = Person.objects.create(name="Paul McCartney")
>>> beatles = Group.objects.create(name="The Beatles")
>>> m1 = Membership(person=ringo, group=beatles,
...     date_joined=date(1962, 8, 16),
...     invite_reason="Needed a new drummer.")
>>> m1.save()
>>> beatles.members.all()
[<Person: Ringo Starr>]
>>> ringo.group_set.all()
[<Group: The Beatles>]
>>> m2 = Membership.objects.create(person=paul, group=beatles,
...     date_joined=date(1960, 8, 1),
...     invite_reason="Wanted to form a band.")
>>> beatles.members.all()
[<Person: Ringo Starr>, <Person: Paul McCartney>]
```